# MySQL Full Text Search odd behaviour

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I made a website for a shop that uses an sql table to manage data about their products.

I used full text search so users can search easily through the stock.

The search runs queries to match the term with the product's brand, name and description, like so:

```
$search_prods = $db_connection->query("

    SELECT      `id`,`name`,`description`
    FROM        `Products`
    WHERE       Match(`brand`) Against('$term')

    UNION

    SELECT      `id`,`name`,`description`
    FROM        `Products`
    WHERE       Match(`description`) Against('$term')

    UNION

    SELECT      `id`,`name`,`description`
    FROM        `Products`
    WHERE       Match(`name`) Against('$term')

    ");
```

The search works fine except when dealing with the brand 'Pandora'. If I search for a different brand, I get my results. If I search for Pandora, I get results with Pandora in the name and results with Pandora in the description. I can't get any results with Pandora in the brand, though. They do exist! I've tried running the queries inside MySql and I get the same issue.

What is it about searching for 'Pandora' in the column 'Brand' that is causing an issue?? Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, MySQL FullText searches [ignore common words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match):

> Words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match.

If over 50% of the products are of the brand "Pandora", then this is the explanation.

You might want to try adding the [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) modifier in your queries to disable this feature.

By the way, you could (read *really should*) rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT id, name, description
FROM Products
WHERE MATCH(brand, description, name) AGAINST('$term' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and thanks for the suggestion. I wrote my query like that originally and it failed. Since the example I was reading from only matched with one column, I assumed it was a limitation of the function. I guess I made a typo first time around or something...

Comment: @user1537360 "*I wrote my query like that originally*" => Are you referring to the first part of my answer (adding `BOOLEAN MODE`) or to the second part (simplifying the query)? My underlying question is: did it solve the problem? ;)

Comment: I meant I originally structured my query like in your suggestion for consolidating all three. After reading your comment, I tried it again and got the same issues, but then I noticed that your query included the Boolean Mode. When I included the Boolean mode, it solved the problem.

As for the problem I was referring to in the OP, you were spot on. The problem was that 5/8 of my demo products were of that brand. I added a few products with other brands and the problem was solved.

I haven't researched this function properly at all because I have been in such a rush, so thanks for the help!